# Writing a trait to use multiple database backends gives me "error[E0597]: `connection` does not live long enough"

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

My program needs to be able to read its data from several databases (Postgres and Oracle).

## Original try

So I thought I would use traits to hide implementations details and a generic function to get at the data. Sadly I need an cheat function to get at the `Transaction` in the case of Postgres backend:

```rust
trait DataSource<'a> {
    fn get_data(&mut self) -> String;
    fn transaction(&mut self) -> &mut postgres::Transaction<'a> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

trait BackendConnection<'a, TS>
where
    TS: DataSource<'a>,
{
    fn data_source(&'a mut self) -> TS;
}

trait BackendConfiguration<'a, TC, TS>
where
    TC: BackendConnection<'a, TS>,
    TS: DataSource<'a>,
{
    fn connect(&self) -> TC;
}

fn generate<'a, TF, TC, TS>(config: &TF)
where
    TF: BackendConfiguration<'a, TC, TS>,
    TC: BackendConnection<'a, TS> + 'a,
    TS: DataSource<'a> + 'a,
{
    let mut connection = config.connect();
    let mut source = connection.data_source();
    println!("{:?}", source.get_data());
}

// You can ignore all this, it is there just to show the reason why the lifetime is needed in `data_source(&'a mut self)` above.
mod pg {
    pub struct PgSource<'a> {transaction: postgres::Transaction<'a>}
    impl<'a> super::DataSource<'a> for PgSource<'a> {
        fn get_data(&mut self) -> String {
            let mut data = String::new();
            for row in self.transaction.query("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", &[]).unwrap() {
                let st: std::time::SystemTime = row.get(0);
                data.push_str(&format!("{:?}\n", st));
            }
            data
        }
        fn transaction(&mut self) -> &mut postgres::Transaction<'a> {
            &mut self.transaction
        }
    }

    pub struct PgConnection {client: postgres::Client}
    impl<'a> super::BackendConnection<'a, PgSource<'a>> for PgConnection {
        fn data_source(&'a mut self) -> PgSource<'a> {
            let transaction = self.client.transaction().unwrap();
            PgSource { transaction }
        }
    }

    pub struct PgConfiguration {config: postgres::Config}
    impl PgConfiguration {
        pub fn new(params: &str) -> Self {
            let config = params.parse::<postgres::Config>().unwrap();
            Self { config }
        }
    }
    impl<'a> super::BackendConfiguration<'a, PgConnection, PgSource<'a>> for PgConfiguration {
        fn connect(&self) -> PgConnection {
            let client = self.config.connect(postgres::tls::NoTls).unwrap();
            PgConnection { client }
        }
    }
}
```

But the [Rust compiler does not accept this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d68aa22eb607315e09827b78369d2ed9):

```
error[E0597]: `connection` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:22:22
   |
17 | fn generate<'a, TF, TC, TS>(config: &TF)
   |             -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
22 |     let mut source = connection.data_source();
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^--------------
   |                      |
   |                      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                      argument requires that `connection` is borrowed for `'a`
23 |     println!("{:?}", source.get_data());
24 | }
   | - `connection` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How can I describe that `connection` overlives `source`? My attempts introducing a scope around `source` or a `'b: 'a` for `connection` did not give positive results.

## Another try with `Box` and associated types

After some comments by Ömer Erden and Kornel I tried boxing the traits and using associated types. [Woohoow, it compiles!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=663b0f8c86e2e46c408e3ffd16958c91):

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]
trait DataSource {
    fn get_data(&mut self) -> String;
    fn transaction(&mut self) -> postgres::Transaction<'_> { unimplemented!() }
}
trait BackendConnection {
    type Source<'a>;
    fn data_source(&mut self) -> Self::Source<'_>;
}
trait BackendConfiguration {
    type Connection;
    fn connect(&self) -> Self::Connection;
}

fn generate<TF>(config: &TF)
where
    TF: BackendConfiguration<Connection=Box<dyn BackendConnection<Source=Box<dyn DataSource>>>>
{
    let mut connection = config.connect();
    let mut source = connection.data_source();
    println!("{:?}", source.get_data());
}

// You can ignore all this, it is there just to show the reason why
// the lifetime is needed in `data_source(&'a mut self)` above.

mod pg {
    pub struct PgSource<'a> {transaction: postgres::Transaction<'a>}
    impl super::DataSource for PgSource<'_> {
        fn get_data(&mut self) -> String {
            let mut data = String::new();
            for row in self.transaction.query("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", &[]).unwrap() {
                let st: std::time::SystemTime = row.get(0);
                data.push_str(&format!("{:?}\n", st));
            }
            data
        }
        fn transaction(&mut self) -> postgres::Transaction<'_> {
            self.transaction.transaction().unwrap()
        }
    }

    pub struct PgConnection {client: postgres::Client}
    impl super::BackendConnection for PgConnection {
        type Source<'a> = Box<PgSource<'a>>;
        fn data_source(&mut self) -> Self::Source<'_> {
            let transaction = self.client.transaction().unwrap();
            Box::new(PgSource { transaction })
        }
    }

    pub struct PgConfiguration {config: postgres::Config}
    impl PgConfiguration {
        pub fn new(params: &str) -> Self {
            let config = params.parse::<postgres::Config>().unwrap();
            Self { config }
        }
    }
    impl super::BackendConfiguration for PgConfiguration {
        type Connection = Box<PgConnection>;
        fn connect(&self) -> Self::Connection {
            let client = self.config.connect(postgres::tls::NoTls).unwrap();
            Box::new(PgConnection { client })
        }
    }
}
```

But it still [fails to compile when I use the generic](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=045d443bee9cbc48cbb2988fa767a8c5):

```rust
fn main() {
    let cfg = pg::PgConfiguration::new("host=host.example user=myself");
    generate(&cfg);
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<pg::PgConfiguration as BackendConfiguration>::Connection == std::boxed::Box<(dyn BackendConnection<Source = std::boxed::Box<(dyn DataSource + 'static)>> + 'static)>`
  --> src/lib.rs:26:5
   |
15 | fn generate<TF>(config: &TF)
   |    --------
16 | where
17 |     TF: BackendConfiguration<Connection=Box<dyn BackendConnection<Source=Box<dyn DataSource>>>>
   |                              ----------------------------------------------------------------- required by this bound in `generate`
...
26 |     generate(&cfg);
   |     ^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn BackendConnection`, found struct `pg::PgConnection`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::boxed::Box<(dyn BackendConnection<Source = std::boxed::Box<(dyn DataSource + 'static)>> + 'static)>`
              found struct `std::boxed::Box<pg::PgConnection>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
```

## Note

If I [monomorphize `generate` by hand it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00aba7a0a827b5bbeec46666af1b8e63):

```rust
fn generate_for_pg(config: &pg::PgConfiguration) {
    let mut connection = config.connect();
    let mut source = connection.data_source();
    println!("{:?}", source.get_data());
}
```

But of course I want to avoid this because it creates code duplication (I'd have to write a `generate_for_oracle`).

Comment: Is there any specific reason for restricting `self` with a lifetime `a` : `fn data_source(&'a mut self) -> TS;` in here? `

Comment: Yes: to implement the `transaction` method. See the second link (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00aba7a0a827b5bbeec46666af1b8e63)

Comment: Can you condense this to a minimal example?

Comment: @Turion you can mostly ignore everything in the `mod pg`: it is there just to show the reason why the lifetime is needed in `data_source(&'a mut self)`

Comment: @kmkaplan, that's true. Your question will be much better though if you delete all these lines we can safely ignore.

Comment: @Turion that's embarassing. If you look at the first version, that code was not there. Then @Ömer Erden questionned the need for `'a' in the `data_source` method. That's why I added the mod. I have now added a comment to in the code to explain it more.

Comment: @kmkaplan I was thinking more along the lines of going away from all the database specific things to an example with just two struct types, one trait, and one polymorphic method.

Comment: @Turion it turns out I can't seem to make it simpler. For example if I remove the `BackendConfiguration` and write a `generate<'a, TC, TS>(connection: &'a mut TC)` then it compiles.

Comment: @kmkaplan obviously because you explicitly state that `connection` lives in `'a`

Comment: @ÖmerErden I thought that `TC: BackendConnection<'a, TS> + 'a` would also state that `connection` lives in `'a`. But I get the feeling that for some reason Rust needs that to be `'static`. May be due to the drop checker.

Comment: @kmkaplan The problem is ``a` represents the caller's lifetime,  caller has more lifetime than the `fn`'s body. `config.connect()` creates new struct inside the `fn`'s body and it dies where the body ends.  This means if you create something inside `fn`'s body it always will live lesser than `'a`. That's why you cannot call `connection.data_source()` because it requires more lifetime for `connection`(due to restriction ->  `&'a mut self'`).

Comment: @ÖmerErden that makes sense. But how would I describe to the compiler that the `'a` only spans the body of `generate`?

Comment: @kmkaplan it is not possible since `TF` comes from outer scope, it all relates with `TF` at the end.

Comment: @ÖmerErden so I should give up trying with generic function and write a specialized `generate_pg` and `generate_ora`, etc?

Comment: @ÖmerErden there's something not quite here. Even if TF is not borrowed (I change `(config: &TF)` to `(config: TF)` the problem persists. But it is in scope then. What's more, the specialized version works (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00aba7a0a827b5bbeec46666af1b8e63)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207186/discussion-between-omer-erden-and-kmkaplan).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing good ever comes from putting lifetime on `&'a mut self`.

When you find yourself doing this, you've dug to deep in the wrong place.

- `&mut` isn't just mutable, it means *exclusive* access. And for safety this exclusivity applies to everything derived from it.
- With shared borrows (`&`) the compiler is pretty flexible and can shorten the lifetimes in places where this is needed, so you can sprinkle `'a` all over the place and it'll work out. But for obscure safety reasons `&mut` lifetimes have to be invariant, i.e. totally inflexible. Can't be shortened, can't be extended.  `&mut self.transaction` is then called a re-borrow, and it creates a new borrow with a new lifetime.

When you have a lifetime on a trait `DataSource<'a>`, and `&mut` makes this lifetime invariant, it ends up meaning that everything `'a` touches had to exist already before the object implementing `DataSource` has been created. And when you mix it with `generate<'a>` it expands that scope to mean everything with that lifetime had to be created even before `genreate` has been called.

I can't run the code, so I'm not sure if that's enough, but you've probably meant:

```
fn transaction<'tmp>(&'tmp mut self) -> &'tmp mut postgres::Transaction<'tmp>
```

simpler written as: (with no `<'a>` on `DataSource`)

```
fn transaction(&mut self) -> &mut postgres::Transaction<'_>
```

which should cast lifetime of `Transaction` to a scope started with that method call, which is as good as you can get anyway because of `&mut` in the return type.

Comment: I have tried doing what you suggest on the transaction method to no avail: I can't make it to compile. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecbd1ab196e2306ee73014eef3f7d7e7
I'll reread you're answer and see if I can make something out of it.

Comment: When you have `Trait<Arg>`, the type of `Arg` is forced on you by the caller, and you're not allowed to decide what `Arg` is (e.g. imagine `Trait<T: Debug>`, you return `String`, but someone calls it on `Trait<i32>` - both implement `Debug`, but string != int). If you want to be dictating the type, you need `Trait { type Assoc; }` and return `Self::Assoc`.

Comment: I tried the associated type approach without success. See the edited question for details.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the following traits:

(Note this still uses some types from tokio-postgres, but it's a step in the right direction)

```rust
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    pub name: String,
    pub user: String,
    pub host: String,
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait Database: Sync + Send {
    type Transaction: Transaction;
    type Connection: Connection<Transaction = Self::Transaction>;

    async fn setup(&mut self, config: Config) -> Result<(), Error>;
    async fn connect(&mut self) -> Result<Self::Connection, Error>;
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait Connection: Sync + Send {
    type Transaction: Transaction;

    async fn transaction(&mut self) -> Result<Self::Transaction, Error>;
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait Transaction: Sync + Send {
    async fn query(
        &self,
        statement: &str,
        params: &[&(dyn ToSql + Sync)],
    ) -> Result<Vec<Row>, Error>;

    async fn query_one(
        &self,
        statement: &str,
        params: &[&(dyn ToSql + Sync)],
    ) -> Result<Row, Error>;

    async fn query_opt(
        &self,
        statement: &str,
        params: &[&(dyn ToSql + Sync)],
    ) -> Result<Option<Row>, Error>;

    async fn commit(self) -> Result<(), Error>;

    async fn rollback(self) -> Result<(), Error>;
}
```

This can be used like this:

```rust
struct Repository<D, T, C>
where
    T: Transaction,
    C: Connection<Transaction = T>,
    D: Database<Transaction = T, Connection = C>,
{
    db: D,
}

#[async_trait]
trait UserRepo {
    async fn get_user(&mut self, txn: &dyn Transaction) -> Result<(), Error>;
}

#[async_trait]
impl<D, T, C> UserRepo for Repository<D, T, C>
where
    T: Transaction,
    C: Connection<Transaction = T>,
    D: Database<Transaction = T, Connection = C>,
{
    async fn get_user(&mut self, txn: &dyn Transaction) -> Result<(), Error> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

All these generic type parameters go away when using the `UserRepo` trait:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    repo: Box<dyn UserRepo>,
}
```

I've created [a code review stack exchange question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276986/a-database-trait-in-rust-how-can-i-make-all-these-generic-parameters-easier-to) for advice on simplifying these trait definitions.

But it works! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of generic associated types you can restrict the generic type to a trait, so you can avoid to wrap everything in box and let the compiler find the types itself:

```rs
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

trait DataSource {
    type Transaction;
    fn get_data(&mut self) -> String;
    fn transaction(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Transaction;
}

trait BackendConnection {
    type Source<'a>: DataSource
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn data_source(&mut self) -> Self::Source<'_>;
}

trait BackendConfiguration {
    type Connection: BackendConnection;
    fn connect(&self) -> Self::Connection;
}

fn generate<TF>(config: &TF)
where
    TF: BackendConfiguration 
{
    let mut connection = config.connect();
    let mut source = connection.data_source();
    println!("{:?}", source.get_data());
}

// You can ignore all this, it is there just to show the reason why the lifetime is needed in `data_source(&'a mut self)` above.
mod pg {
    pub struct PgSource<'a> {
        transaction: postgres::Transaction<'a>,
    }
    impl<'a> super::DataSource for PgSource<'a> {
        type Transaction = postgres::Transaction<'a>;
        fn get_data(&mut self) -> String {
            let mut data = String::new();
            for row in self
                .transaction
                .query("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", &[])
                .unwrap()
            {
                let st: std::time::SystemTime = row.get(0);
                data.push_str(&format!("{:?}\n", st));
            }
            data
        }
        fn transaction(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Transaction {
            &mut self.transaction
        }
    }

    pub struct PgConnection {
        client: postgres::Client,
    }
    impl super::BackendConnection for PgConnection {
        type Source<'a> = PgSource<'a>;

        fn data_source(&mut self) -> PgSource<'_> {
            let transaction = self.client.transaction().unwrap();
            PgSource { transaction }
        }
    }

    pub struct PgConfiguration {
        config: postgres::Config,
    }
    impl PgConfiguration {
        pub fn new(params: &str) -> Self {
            let config = params.parse::<postgres::Config>().unwrap();
            Self { config }
        }
    }
    impl super::BackendConfiguration for PgConfiguration {
        type Connection = PgConnection;
        fn connect(&self) -> PgConnection {
            let client = self.config.connect(postgres::tls::NoTls).unwrap();
            PgConnection { client }
        }
    }

}

fn main() {
    let cfg = pg::PgConfiguration::new("host=host.example user=myself");
    generate(&cfg);
}
```

Here no problem calling the generate function with the fake type